# Add Commands to WinForms

Tags: winforms, powershell

I got the following WinForm. How can I add commands to it?

The SamAccountName Field is for for the User/Group name. How do I catch this input?

The list shoud be a list with 2 entries:

1. user
2. group

This is the point where the user decides wether it's a group or a user and it would be awesome if I could somehow save that in a variable.

The search button should trigger the actual commands (a wildcard search for user or group).

`$DataGridView1` should display the output of the executed commands.

The executed code would be: (User OR Groups is separated from the WinForms I'm not sure how to format it right)

User:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -like '*$find*' -or DisplayName -like '*$find*' -or Description -like '*$find*' -or DistinguishedName -like '*$find*' -or Mail -like '*$find*'" -Properties * |
    Sort-Object |
    Format-Table SamAccountName, DisplayName
```

Group:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$find*'" -Properties * |
    Sort-Object |
    Format-Table SamAccountName, Description
```

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '692,401'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$SamAccountName                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$SamAccountName.multiline        = $false
$SamAccountName.width            = 100
$SamAccountName.height           = 20
$SamAccountName.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,30)
$SamAccountName.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Search                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Search.text                     = "button"
$Search.width                    = 60
$Search.height                   = 30
$Search.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(143,30)
$Search.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$DataGridView1                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView1.width             = 675
$DataGridView1.height            = 250
$DataGridView1.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(9,135)

$User                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$User.text                       = "User"
$User.AutoSize                   = $false
$User.width                      = 95
$User.height                     = 13
$User.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,72)
$User.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Group                           = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Group.text                      = "Group"
$Group.AutoSize                  = $false
$Group.width                     = 95
$Group.height                    = 20
$Group.location                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,94)
$Group.Font                      = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($SamAccountName,$Search,$DataGridView1,$User,$Group))

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at [PowerShell Studio](https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio). It allows you to easily create forms with events, these events trigger some action, like running a CmdLet for example.

Comment: I have found a page where you can build the GUI and add events, I'm still not getting how that work, it would be nice if someone could show me how with my provided code :)

Comment: Check the [tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25911.how-to-add-a-powershell-gui-event-handler-part-1.aspx)

Comment: Add a radio button to select "user" or "group", and assign an action to the button that will run one query or the other depending on the value of the radio button.

Comment: i have added 2 checkboxes instead is that okay.

Comment: i did already get some help on reddit :D For those who are interested in the solution => https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/cq90rw/ad_script_to_winform/